# jQuery - adding class to li on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup

```
<div id="div1">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="id1">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="id2">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="id3">link3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to add a class to the clicked link and remove the class from previously clicked links, like

```
<li class="selected"><a href="#" id="id1">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id2">link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="id3">link3</a></li>
```

Comment: If you search a bit in Google, Bing and others, you will find a lot of blog entries and tutorials about this

Comment: in the future don't just come here to get the answer... try to do it yourself first.

Comment: Sorry, will be careful next time. Though I tried some code before posting this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#div1 li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to attach the `click` event to the `a`:

```
$('#div1 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div1 a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YSYpw/)

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    $('li a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

That is, first remove all the classes, then add the class to the one that has been clicked.